# Specific theme for non logged in users

Tags: themes, users, login, customization

I want to make an specific theme for non logged in users, but I don´t know how to make the function or plugin to shift the theme for them, and left another specific theme for logged in users.

Anyone knows how to do this? The only clues I had are the functions `switch_theme` and `is_user_logged_in`, but don´t know how to make them work to do this.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

You can override the theme WordPress uses with the `template` and `stylesheet` filters:

```
/**
 * Override the current theme to show non-logged in users.
 * 
 * @link    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/142418/1685
 * 
 * @param   string  $theme
 * @return  string
 */
function wpse_142418_nopriv_theme( $theme ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) 
        $theme = 'mythemefoldername';
    return $theme;
}

add_filter( 'stylesheet', 'wpse_142418_nopriv_theme' );
add_filter( 'template',   'wpse_142418_nopriv_theme' );
```

Comment: As @kaiser mentioned, `switch_theme` will make relentless updates to the DB. Using these filters will not.

Comment: And that's why I upvoted you :)

Comment: Works for child themes and parent themes?

Comment: If you just want to override a child theme, use only the `stylesheet` filter.

Answer (score 4):

## Functions - under the hood

While `is_user_logged_in()` can be used to determine the difference between a guest and a logged in (and therefore registered) user, `switch_theme( $stylesheet )` alters actual database entries in the `{$wpdb->options}` table:

```
update_option( 'template', $template );
update_option( 'stylesheet', $stylesheet );
update_option( 'current_theme', $new_name );
if ( count( $wp_theme_directories ) > 1 ) {
    update_option( 'template_root', get_raw_theme_root( $template, true ) );
    update_option( 'stylesheet_root', get_raw_theme_root( $stylesheet, true ) );
} else {
    delete_option( 'template_root' );
    delete_option( 'stylesheet_root' );
}
update_option( 'theme_switched', $old_theme->get_stylesheet() );
```

## Simple solution: Two stylesheets.

Therefore I wouldn't recommend doing so. Simply switch "themes" - read: loaded stylesheets - on a user/guest basis

```
$stylesheet  = plugins_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'assets/';
$stylesheet .= is_user_logged_in()
    ? 'style-user.css'
    : 'style-guest.css;
wp_enqueue_style(
    'main-stylesheet',
    $stylesheet
    array( 'commons.css' )
    1.0
);
```

As you can see, I add a dependency of `commons.css` to the stylesheet. This would be another, previously registered/enqueued stylesheet that has all definitions that are shared between both.

Comment: Like your two stylesheets method. +1